# How to create logarithmic function with base x in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a logarithmic function with base x then plot it: y=logx10.
So I use:

```
   y= math.log(10,x)
```

but it returned an error said: only length-1 array can be converted to Python scalars.
So what is the correct way to create a log function with base x?

Comment: what type is `x`?

Comment: random variable with a range(0.02,0.91)

Comment: This is working ok for me: setting `x=2`, then `math.log(1024,x)` returns `10.0`

Comment: Using `x=random.uniform(1,5)`, then `math.log(1024,x)` returned `31.119969....`. How are you generating your random number?

Comment: I want to make it a function then plot it, so I use x=linspace(0.02,0.91) first

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to get a "smoother" line is by increasing the number of points (i.e., make `length` bigger.)

Also, you likely want to sort your x list before calculating and plotting:

```py
length = 100   # or higher
      :    
x = sorted([random.uniform(rand_min, rand_max) for r in xrange(length)])
y = [math.log(10, _x) for _x in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want 2 lists of values `(x, y)`, you will have to generate the `x` list first, and use it to generate the `y` list:

```
import math
import random

length = 10
rand_min = 0.02
rand_max = 0.91

x = [random.uniform(rand_min, rand_max) for r in xrange(length)]
y = [math.log(10, _x) for _x in x]
```

Here you have lists `x` and `y`, both of length `length`.

Comment: Thx, is there anyway I can make it continues? This is discrete I think, so when I plot it, it can not show me a line.

Comment: it seems cannot generate the correct result. Since I set the x range(0.02,0.91) then the range of x-axis should from 0.02 to 0.91, but the output plot shows the x-axis range is from 0 to 10

Comment: @AlexZ If you want it random it will not be continuous. If you sort it, there is not much sense in the use of random. If the plotting range is wrong, how do you plot...edit or new question?